# object of type NoneType has no len

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def medianeven (L):
    while len(L) > 2:
        L = L[1:(len(L)-1)]
    return average (L)

def medianodd (L):
    while len(L) > 1:
        L = L[1:(len(L)-1)]
    return L[0]

def median (L):
    new = L.sort()
    a = len(new)
    if a % 2 == 0:
        medianeven(new)
    else:
        medianodd(new)
```

It says `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`.  Both `medianeven` and `medianodd` work, but `median` itself is not functioning.

Answer (score 7):

`.sort()` is in-place and returns `None`.

Change this line:

```
new = L.sort()
```

To just this:

```
L.sort()
```

And replace all of your instances of `new` with just `L`. You also need to `return` the results of those function calls:

```
if a % 2 == 0:
    return medianeven(new)
else:
    return medianodd(new)
```

Also, Python's slices support negative indices, so this code:

```
L[1:(len(L)-1)]
```

Can be simplified to just

```
L[1:-1]
```

Comment: If he changes new = L.sort() to just L.sort() then he needs to set new = L on the next line or replace the calls to len(new), medianeven(new), and medianodd(new) with len(L), medianeven(L), and medianodd(L).

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method call you have in the line:

```
new = L.sort();
```

doesn't return anything. Thus 'new' holds 'None', which has no length. I believe doing L.sort() will sort the list in place. Don't need to store it in 'new'.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon now, or else